# What ever happened to Clara Oswald?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode *Doctor Who* "Hell bent", Clara disappeared with Me in the diner and because of this, I assumed she survived and left to go on her own adventures.

However, in 12's regeneration episode, Clara is seen again wearing the same clothes she was wearing when she died and the Doctor was talking to her like she was dead. So did she not actually survive Hell bent or did she die somewhere between those 2 episodes?

Comment: If it helps anyone, there's a plot synopsis on https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Clara_Oswald - which, tbh, lost me by the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Who is "Me" in the first sentence here?  I've looked at the plot description and cannot match it with any character name.

Comment: It's Ashildr. She calls herself Me in "The Woman Who Lived" because she's been alive so long, she forgot who she was or something  like that. https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Ashildr

Answer (score 1):

Clara wasn't really there when he saw her right before regenerating. That was a vision that he had as his memories of her came back. And at that point, he would assume that she's dead. Now that he has his memories of her back, he knows that she knew that time would be destroyed if she wasn't placed back at the time of her death. So, I'm sure he assumes that she went back to Gallifrey to have them put her back.

And really, we as the audience don't even know if she's dead again, at this point. Yeah, we had her final scene, where she says they'll take "the long way round" to go back to Gallifrey, implying that she'll go on some adventures with Ashildr before going back to her death, but we have no way of knowing if she's still doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The scene you are recalling was not real. The Doctor was imagining her. Cinematographically, it makes more sense to have the actor appear and an actual conversation take place, as opposed to the Doctor thinking in silence. But in reality, the Doctor was simply thinking about Clara and having an imaginary conversation with her. She was wearing the same clothes as the last time he saw her because that's how he remembers her.

As to Clara's overall fate, she jumped in the Doctor's frayed timeline when they visited Trenzalore. In a sense, the real Clara died there. But she also spread herself over the Doctor's timeline, meaning that the Doctor meets different Claras during his lifetime.

The first Clara he met (in order of episodes) is the one who was turned into a Dalek. She is a different Clara than the one you know ("companion Clara"), as the Doctor never met "Dalek Clara" before she was turned into a Dalek, and she dies at the end of that episode.